# How can I convert a String to an Int in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working in a small project and I faced this problem : text field is String by default so I need to take the input and convert it to integer then calculate I was searching for a way to solve the converting problem and I didn't find any working solution so can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
try like this
```

In Swift 2.0, `toInt()`,replaced with initializers. (In this case, Int(someString).)

```
 let myString : String = "50"
    let x : Int? = Int(myString)

    if (x != null) {
       // converted String to Int
    }
```

Comment: not worked in swift 2.x

Comment: ParaSara now check @ParaSara

Answer (score 0):

`myString.toInt()` - convert the string value into int .